# Why has it become preferable to put the definite article in 'Here are the details about…'

Tags: definite-articles

Consider the phrases

> Here are details about…

> Here are the details about…

If you look at google books, both versions exist in edited books written by native speakers. But google NGrams shows that the overall preference for one version over another has flipped over the past several decades:

[image]

Why is this? Is it correlated with other changes in the language?

Comment: To my ears, "Here are the details" sounds as though it would be more complete. "Here are details" can read like "Here are some details." As to the "flip," perhaps, with the advent of **cut & paste composition**, it is more likely that you are indeed supplying all the details: someone has compiled them, and you can easily pass them all on.

Comment: Definite descriptions presuppose existence, and in a plural, completeness. Anarthrous descriptions do not.

Comment: By the way, I'm guessing narrowing the phrases that tightly (a search that excludes, e.g. "I have [the] details about" or "find out [the] details about") yields a sample size too small to take the trends over time as statistically reliable.